# Сохранение переменных Python

Tags: python

Код :

```
price = 0

def change_price():
   price = 1

def show_price():
   print(price)

change_price()
show_price()
```

`show_price` отдаёт 0. Мне нужно изменять и сохранять переменную, как это сделать? Почему переменная не сохраняется? Если обозначать `price = 1` в `show_price`, отдаст 1.

Я не понимаю в питоне, как это работает?

Comment: В функции `change_price` переменная `price` является локальной, потому что Вы не сказали, что эту переменную необходимо искать в глобальной области видимости. Для этого перед изменением переменой скажите интерпретатору, что она глобальная. `global price`. Но использование глобальных переменных это **очень** плохая практика, этого стоит избегать.

Comment: Добавил global, syntax error

Comment: show_price() ничего никуда не отдает. Возьмите учебник и прочитайте главу о функциях.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

В функции `change_price` переменная `price` является локальной, потому что Вы не сказали, что эту переменную необходимо искать в глобальной области видимости. Для этого перед изменением переменой скажите интерпретатору, что она глобальная:

```py
def f():
    global price
    price = 1
```

Но использование глобальных переменных это очень плохая практика, этого стоит избегать.

---

Во второй функции переменная тоже сначала ищется в локальной области видимости, не находится и только после этого ищется в глобальной.

Answer (score 0):

Есть 2 варианта.
Использовать `global`(что не очень хорошая практика)

```
price = 0

def change_price():
   global price
   price = 1

def show_price():
   print(price)

change_price()
show_price()
```

Либо передать переменную аргументом функции и использовать `return`:

```
price = 0

def change_price(price):
   price = 1
   return price

def show_price(price):
   print(price)

price = change_price(price)
show_price(price)
```

Answer (score 0):

```
class Price:
    def __init__(self, value=0):
        self.value: float
        self.value = value

    def increase(self, value) -> None:
        self.value += value


p = Price(152)
print(p.value)
p.increase(20)
print(p.value)
# 152
# 172
```