Как сохранить данные, которые ввел пользователь в Python?
Такой вопрос: Делаю программу-калькулятор, в которой пользователь может подсчитать свою прибыль в игре. Хочу сделать так, чтобы при запуске программы создавался файл .txt, если его нет и туда записывалось значение all_profit_label, то есть сумма введенных чисел пользователем (Прибыль за все время). 
При следующем запуске значение бралось оттуда и выводилось.
Как мне это сделать? 
Мне писали о том, что я вставляю слишком много кода сюда, но т.к. я новичок, я не знаю что из кода можешь пригодиться для того, чтобы вы все правильно поняли.
from PyQt6 import QtCore, QtGui, QtWidgets


class Ui_MainWindow(object):
    def setupUi(self, MainWindow):
        MainWindow.setObjectName("MainWindow")
        MainWindow.setFixedSize(300, 400)
        font = QtGui.QFont()
        font.setBold(False)
        font.setWeight(50)
        MainWindow.setFont(font)
        MainWindow.setStyleSheet("background-color: rgb(228, 228, 228);")
        self.centralwidget = QtWidgets.QWidget(parent=MainWindow)
        self.centralwidget.setObjectName("centralwidget")
        self.label = QtWidgets.QLabel(parent=self.centralwidget)
        self.label.setGeometry(QtCore.QRect(20, 20, 120, 20))
        self.label.setStyleSheet("color: rgb(0, 0, 0);" "font: 13pt \".AppleSystemUIFont\";")
        self.label.setObjectName("label")
        self.pushButton = QtWidgets.QPushButton(parent=self.centralwidget)
        self.pushButton.setGeometry(QtCore.QRect(20, 65, 160, 20))
        self.pushButton.setStyleSheet("color: rgb(255, 255, 255);\n"
"background-color: rgb(119, 221, 119);")
        self.pushButton.setObjectName("pushButton")
        self.label_2 = QtWidgets.QLabel(parent=self.centralwidget)
        self.label_2.setGeometry(QtCore.QRect(20, 120, 120, 20))
        self.label_2.setStyleSheet("color: rgb(0, 0, 0);" "font: 13pt \".AppleSystemUIFont\";")
        self.label_2.setObjectName("label_2")
        self.all_profit_label = QtWidgets.QLabel(parent=self.centralwidget)
        self.all_profit_label.setGeometry(QtCore.QRect(145, 120, 120, 20))
        self.all_profit_label.setStyleSheet("color: rgb(0, 0, 0);" "font: 13pt \".AppleSystemUIFont\";")
        self.all_profit_label.setObjectName("all_profit_label")
        self.lineEdit = QtWidgets.QLineEdit(parent=self.centralwidget)
        self.lineEdit.setGeometry(QtCore.QRect(20, 40, 160, 20))
        self.lineEdit.setStyleSheet("color: rgb(0, 0, 0);")
        self.lineEdit.setObjectName("lineEdit")
        MainWindow.setCentralWidget(self.centralwidget)
        self.menubar = QtWidgets.QMenuBar(parent=MainWindow)
        self.menubar.setGeometry(QtCore.QRect(0, 0, 300, 24))
        self.menubar.setObjectName("menubar")
        MainWindow.setMenuBar(self.menubar)
        self.statusbar = QtWidgets.QStatusBar(parent=MainWindow)
        self.statusbar.setObjectName("statusbar")
        MainWindow.setStatusBar(self.statusbar)

        self.retranslateUi(MainWindow)
        QtCore.QMetaObject.connectSlotsByName(MainWindow)

        self.add_functions()

    def retranslateUi(self, MainWindow):
        _translate = QtCore.QCoreApplication.translate
        MainWindow.setWindowTitle(_translate("MainWindow", "PerekupCalculator | v. 1.5"))
        self.label.setText(_translate("MainWindow", "Введите сумму:"))
        self.pushButton.setText(_translate("MainWindow", "Добавить"))
        self.label_2.setText(_translate("MainWindow", "Заработано всего:"))
        self.all_profit_label.setText(_translate("MainWindow", "0"))

    def add_functions(self):
        self.pushButton.clicked.connect(self.add_profit)
        self.pushButton.setAutoDefault(True)
        self.lineEdit.returnPressed.connect(self.pushButton.click)

    def add_profit(self):
        try:
            all_profit = int(self.all_profit_label.text()) + \
                         int(self.lineEdit.text())
            self.all_profit_label.setNum(all_profit)
            self.lineEdit.clear()
        except Exception as e:
            msg = QtWidgets.QMessageBox.information(
                self, 
                'Внимание! Что-то пошло не так!', 
                f'{e}')


if __name__ == "__main__":
    import sys
    app = QtWidgets.QApplication(sys.argv)
    MainWindow = QtWidgets.QMainWindow()
    ui = Ui_MainWindow()
    ui.setupUi(MainWindow)
    MainWindow.show()
    sys.exit(app.exec())


Заранее спасибо всем откликнувшимся и заранее прошу прощения, если мой вопрос сформулирован неправильно, я только начинаю свой путь в программировании и могу допускать ошибки.

martysue3005, ваш вопрос сформулирован нормально. Как задать хороший вопрос - читаем   https://ru.stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask . Код, который вы публикуете - должен быть минимально-воспроизводимый и демонстрировать проблему. Вы также должны рассказать/показать свои попытки  решения проблемы и что у вас не получается. На данный момент ваш проект  маленький и минимизировать его нет смысла. Почему вы решили, что надо создавать файл .txt? Ответ на вопрос  https://ru.stackoverflow.com/questions/1582187 решает вашу проблему?

S. Nick, указанный вами ответ в теме, ссылку на которую вы скинули у меня не работает. Это может быть связано с тем, что у меня MacOS? Что выводит терминал скину позже

martysue3005, странно вы как-то пишите, что у вас что-то, где-то не работает. Лучше бы вы так не писали.

S. Nick, что вы имеете ввиду?

martysue3005, я имею ввиду ваш первый комментарий.

S. Nick, я получаю ошибку в терминале, используя ваш код: AttributeError: type object 'QSettings' has no attribute 'IniFormat'. Did you mean: 'Format'?

martysue3005, Emums изменились в PyQt6, вам нужно полное имя:
QtCore.QSettings.Format.IniFormat

S. Nick, спасибо, работает. Вы можете добавить это в качестве ответа сюда и я помечу его как полезный

martysue3005, пожалуйста, но я что-то не понимаю. разве вопрос на который я дал ответ, не ваш?

НИКОГДА НЕ ИЗМЕНЯЙТЕ код, сгенерированный Qt Designer, НИКОГДА.
Создайте другой класс, который наследуется от соответствующего виджета, и используйте созданный класс для его заполнения.
Класс QSettings обеспечивает постоянные, независимые от платформы настройки приложения.
# from PyQt6 import QtCore, QtGui, QtWidgets               # PyQt6 
from PyQt5 import QtCore, QtGui, QtWidgets                 # PyQt5 


class Ui_MainWindow(object):
    def setupUi(self, MainWindow):
        MainWindow.setObjectName("MainWindow")
        MainWindow.resize(300, 400)
        font = QtGui.QFont()
        font.setBold(False)
        font.setWeight(50)
        MainWindow.setFont(font)
        MainWindow.setStyleSheet("background-color: rgb(228, 228, 228);")
        self.centralwidget = QtWidgets.QWidget(parent=MainWindow)
        self.centralwidget.setObjectName("centralwidget")
        self.label = QtWidgets.QLabel(parent=self.centralwidget)
        self.label.setGeometry(QtCore.QRect(20, 20, 120, 20))
        self.label.setStyleSheet("font: 13pt \".AppleSystemUIFont\";")
        self.label.setObjectName("label")
        self.pushButton = QtWidgets.QPushButton(parent=self.centralwidget)
        self.pushButton.setGeometry(QtCore.QRect(20, 65, 160, 20))
        self.pushButton.setStyleSheet("color: rgb(255, 255, 255);\n"
"background-color: rgb(119, 221, 119);")
        self.pushButton.setObjectName("pushButton")
        self.label_2 = QtWidgets.QLabel(parent=self.centralwidget)
        self.label_2.setGeometry(QtCore.QRect(20, 120, 120, 20))
        self.label_2.setObjectName("label_2")
        self.all_profit_label = QtWidgets.QLabel(parent=self.centralwidget)
        self.all_profit_label.setGeometry(QtCore.QRect(145, 120, 120, 20))
        self.all_profit_label.setObjectName("all_profit_label")
        self.lineEdit = QtWidgets.QLineEdit(parent=self.centralwidget)
        self.lineEdit.setGeometry(QtCore.QRect(20, 40, 160, 20))
        self.lineEdit.setObjectName("lineEdit")
        MainWindow.setCentralWidget(self.centralwidget)
        self.menubar = QtWidgets.QMenuBar(parent=MainWindow)
        self.menubar.setGeometry(QtCore.QRect(0, 0, 300, 24))
        self.menubar.setObjectName("menubar")
        MainWindow.setMenuBar(self.menubar)
        self.statusbar = QtWidgets.QStatusBar(parent=MainWindow)
        self.statusbar.setObjectName("statusbar")
        MainWindow.setStatusBar(self.statusbar)

        self.retranslateUi(MainWindow)
        QtCore.QMetaObject.connectSlotsByName(MainWindow)

#        self.add_functions()

    def retranslateUi(self, MainWindow):
        _translate = QtCore.QCoreApplication.translate
        MainWindow.setWindowTitle(_translate("MainWindow", "PerekupCalculator | v. 1.0.0"))
        self.label.setText(_translate("MainWindow", "Введите сумму:"))
        self.pushButton.setText(_translate("MainWindow", "Добавить"))
        self.label_2.setText(_translate("MainWindow", "Заработано всего:"))
        self.all_profit_label.setText(_translate("MainWindow", "0"))


class MainWindow(QtWidgets.QMainWindow, Ui_MainWindow):                 # !!!
    def __init__(self):
        super().__init__()
        self.setupUi(self)                                              # !!!

        self.add_functions()
        
# +++ vvvvvvvvvvvvvvvvvvvvvvvvvvvvvvvvvvvvvvvvvvvvvvvvvvvvvvvvvvvvvvvvvvvvvvvvv 
        self.load_settings()

    def load_settings(self):
        settings = QtCore.QSettings(
            "q1582187_settings.ini", QtCore.QSettings.IniFormat)                # PyQt5 
#           "q1582187_settings.ini", QtCore.QSettings.Format.IniFormat)         # PyQt6 
    
        self.all_profit_label.setText(settings.value('all_profit_label', "0"))

    def save_settings(self):
        settings = QtCore.QSettings(
            "q1582187_settings.ini", QtCore.QSettings.IniFormat)
        settings.setValue("all_profit_label", self.all_profit_label.text())

    def closeEvent(self, event):
            self.save_settings()
            event.accept()
# +++ ^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^            
        
    def add_functions(self):
        self.pushButton.clicked.connect(self.add_profit)
        self.lineEdit.returnPressed.connect(self.pushButton.click)
        self.lineEdit.setFocus()

    def add_profit(self):
        try:
            all_profit = int(self.all_profit_label.text()) + \
                         int(self.lineEdit.text())
            self.all_profit_label.setNum(all_profit)
            self.lineEdit.clear()
            self.lineEdit.setFocus()                                     # +
        except Exception as e:
            msg = QtWidgets.QMessageBox.information(
                self, 
                'Внимание! Что-то пошло не так!', 
                f'{e}')
            


if __name__ == "__main__":
    import sys

    app = QtWidgets.QApplication(sys.argv)
# +++
    app.setStyleSheet("""
        #all_profit_label {
            font-size: 13pt;
            color: #C81912;
        }
        """)
    w = MainWindow()                                                    # !!!
    w.show()
    sys.exit(app.exec())



@martysue3005 что не так?

при создании из .py файла .app для MacOS, используя инструмент pyinstaller, данные перестают сохраняться. Файл не создается. Что в таком случае делать?

данные не сохраняются даже если я сам перемещу файл settings.ini в папку с программой .app

@martysue3005 если у вас есть другие проблемы - задайте новый вопрос. Хорошо расскажите, что вы хотите сделать, какие действия вы выполняете и что у вас не получается. Опубликуйте код, с которым у вас возникают проблемы и опишите какие версии ПО вы используете.

https://ru.stackoverflow.com/questions/1582457
