Не работает сохранение данных после использования pyinstaller
В своей программе я сохраняю данные из all_profit_lable и all_day_profit_lable таким образом:
    def load_settings(self):
        settings = QtCore.QSettings(
            "settings.ini", QtCore.QSettings.Format.IniFormat) 
        self.all_profit_label.setText(settings.value('all_profit_label', "0"))
        self.all_day_profit_label.setText(settings.value('all_profit_label', "0"))

    def save_settings(self):
        settings = QtCore.QSettings(
            "settings.ini", QtCore.QSettings.Format.IniFormat)
        settings.setValue("all_profit_label", self.all_profit_label.text())
        settings.setValue("all_day_profit_label", self.all_day_profit_label.text())

    def closeEvent(self, event):
            self.save_settings()
            event.accept() 

Используя pyinstaller и запуская свою программу через .app файл - сохранение не работает. Файл .ini не создается. Сохранение не работает, даже если я сам перемещу settings.ini к программе. Что мне сделать, чтобы все работало?
